# Why would a KVM/Qemu VM, running successfully on a new host, get stuck "Paused" after a few minutes?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

I used virsh commands to backup a Xubuntu 22.04 VM on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine and restore it on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

The VM starts up successfully, but after a few minutes of running `apt` updates it hangs up in "Paused" state and after a forced shutdown will restart and "Pause" immediately.

Initially, I could not get it to start at all due to:

```
 unsupported machine type 'pc-q35-4.2'
```

I was able to fix that with `virsh edit`, changing this line ...

```
 <os>
   <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-4.2'>hvm</type>
 </os>
```

... to this ...

```
 <os>
   <type arch='x86_64' machine='q35'>hvm</type>
 </os>
```

It is very likely to be a versions problem.  The original host (20.04) has:

```
 QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.23)
```

The new host (18.04) has:

```
 QEMU emulator version 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.40)
```

**Questions**

1. could there be a different reason for the failure?
2. is it possible to upgrade `QEMU 2.11.1` to  `QEMU 4.2.1` on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine?
3. is it possible to upgrade Virtual Manager from `1.5.1` to  `2.2.1` on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine?
4. what else would I need to upgrade?

Comment: it might be possible but it's a dead end and not a supported case on serverfault.com due it should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices in a business environment.

Comment: @djdomi If this is the wrong forum, please tell me the correct one.

Comment: you can try on superuser.com but I ain't sure if that's the same situation